# Kendo TreeView default selected node doesn't trigger onSelect

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

My php code creates a hierarchical json dataset for the hierarchicalDataSource used by a treeview.

In this php generating function, i set the very first leaf as selected=true... so when the treeview appears, the first leaf is automatically selected.

The problem is that when the user clicks any leaf, an event (onSelect) is triggered but it is not triggered for this automatic selection of the very first node that occurs when the treeview appears at UI creation time.

How can i fix this ?

UPDATE:
[Made a Demo: http://jsbin.com/abapid/2/edit](http://jsbin.com/abapid/2/edit)

Comment: Could you make some code showing it? It uses to easier fix someone else problems than have to write it and maybe not reproducing the problem.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/abapid/2/edit

Comment: It works! What is not working? If I click on "Tables & Chairs" it popups the alert window.

Comment: It should popup right from the start with "Tables & Chairs" being initially selected... As soon as JS Bin paints the TreeView widget, the onSelect needs to be called. I know it doesn't by design but i need a way to make it happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the benefits of others.... and thanks to **OnaBai** !... Here is the solution !

Kendo UI lacks many basic features other UI SDK always provide. One of them is an "onDisplay" kind of even that gets triggered once the widget gets painted. This would allow the application to react to specific case like in mine where the dataSource loaded a node containing a "selected = true" field.

The Kendo TreeView reacts by showing the node as selected but in most real world scenarios, the application would also need to react. That is why it would need to be called upon widget initialization to check if a node is selected and react accordingly.

The only hack we (**OnaBai**) found is to use the "DataBound" event as an "onDisplay" kind of event. The hic is that this event is fired each time a parent node as a child that got modified somehow. So it is called multiple times.

So here is the code to go around this limitation!
http://jsbin.com/ejabul/4/edit  (Note that you must click the "Run  with JS" to simulate a page reload)

```
 $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource:data,
    dataTextField: "text",
    select: onSelect,
    dataBound: function (e) {
    var uid = undefined;
    var now = this.select();
    if (now) {
        var data = this.dataItem(now);
        uid = data.uid;
        if (uid && uid !== this.old_selected) {
            alert("Bingo !");
        }
        console.log("data", data.uid);
    }
    this.old_selected = uid;
    }
});
```

Explanation by **OnaBai**

> 1. Store in uid the Unique ID of the selected item. This ID is introduced by Kendo UI for most node, items, … that it creates. Initially I set it to undefined (just in case there is nothing selected)
> 2. "now" contains current selected node (if any).
> 3. If there is an element selected (now !== undefined) then I get the data item for the selected node and then get the UID for this node.
> 4. If there is a UID and if different than the UID of the previous selected node (that I store in a field that I just extended in the tree_view and I called old_selected) then I alert.
> 5. finally I save the UID of the selected node for the next time.
>
> Basically what I try is to control that I do not alert two consecutive times for the same node and for controlling it I save the UID of the selected node from one iteration to the next.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to programmatically trigger a `select` event, you should do:

```
$("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView").trigger("select");
```

Comment: Yes but then the other problem is that i have no-where to place that call... There are no "onShow" event for the TreeView that would allow me to react as soon as the TreeView gets painted....

Comment: Why not in `dataBound` event?

Comment: Because a C++ developper like me who creates UI applications with Win32, QT, OSF/MOTIF... is used to look for the API function onShow !... Thanks man !

Comment: Um! Actually it gets called several times because each level loads separately http://jsbin.com/ejabul/1/edit... Just added an alert

Comment: In `dataBound` if you want to get the selected node do `this.select()`.  If you want to get the model do `this.dataItem(this.select());` Remember, in the context of the event, `this` is the tree.

Comment: Maybe it is easier if you explain me what you end up willing to do since maybe there is some clean way of doing it. What is what you want to do in that _fake_ initial select?